# Registering a listener for composite item writer to use @beforestep method

Tags: spring-batch

I have the following spring batch config. My reader , processor, writer are decided on runtime based on some config.

```
    public Job batchJob(Map<String, Object> jobParametersMap) throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("springBatchJob")
                .start(chunkStep(jobParametersMap))
                .listener(jobExecutionListener(jobParametersMap))
                .build();
    }

    public Step chunkStep(Map<String, Object> jobParametersMap) {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.convertValue(jobParametersMap.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        int chunkSize = jobContext.getFileProcessingConfig().getChunkSize();
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("fileProcessingStep")
                .chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(reader(jobParametersMap))
                .processor(processor(jobParametersMap))
                .writer(writer(jobParametersMap))
                .build();
    }

    public ItemReader<?> reader(Map<String, Object> jobParametersMap) {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.convertValue(jobParametersMap.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        StepHandler config = jobContext.getFileProcessingConfig().getReaderConfig();
        return stepHandlerFactory.getReader(config);
    }

    public ItemProcessor processor(Map<String, Object> jobParametersMap) {
        JobContext jobContext = mapper.convertValue(jobParametersMap.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        StepHandler config = jobContext.getFileProcessingConfig().getProcessorConfig();
        return stepHandlerFactory.getProcessor(config);
    }

    public ItemWriter<?> writer(Map<String, Object> jobParametersMap) {
        CompositeItemWriter itemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
        List<ItemWriter<?>> itemWriterList = new ArrayList<>();

        JobContext jobContext = mapper.convertValue(jobParametersMap.get(BATCH_JOB_CONTEXT), JobContext.class);
        List<StepHandler> config = jobContext.getFileProcessingConfig().getWriterConfig();
        config.forEach(writerConfig -> itemWriterList.add(stepHandlerFactory.getWriter(writerConfig)));
        itemWriter.setDelegates(itemWriterList);
        return itemWriter;
    }
```

this is one of my itemWriter implementation.

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<JsonNode> {
    private ExecutionContext executionContext;
    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) throws IOException {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        executionContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends JsonNode> items) {
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is my @BeforeStep method is not being called in the item writer.
I want to use that method to set my execution context. I think it is because, my itemWriters are inside CompositeItemWriter.

I am not sure what how to register this compositeItemWriter or its delegates to the listener.

How can i resolve this ?

Big Thanks to further help.

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is because, my itemWriters are inside CompositeItemWriter.

Yes, when using a composite writer, the delegates should be registered as streams manually.

This is mentioned in the documentation here: [Registering ItemStream with a Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/step/chunk-oriented-processing/registering-item-streams.html)

> I am not sure what how to register this compositeItemWriter or its delegates to the listener.

In the step builder, you can call `.listener()` and pass the delegate writer as a parameter.